# Sum of two dependent vectors is dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am trying to prove that, given two linearly independent vectors ${v_1, v_2}$, the sum of vectors $v_3+v_4$ (both being some linear combination of $v_1, v_2$) is linearly dependent with $v_1, v_2$.

It makes sense to me intuitively since if we have $x_1 v_1+x_2v_2=v_3$ and $y_1v_1+y_2v_2=v_4$, then $v_3+v_4=x_1 v_1+x_2v_2+y_1v_1+y_2v_2$, but I'm struggling to formulate a proof using the definition of linear dependency. Any suggestions on how I might do so?

Comment: What does it mean for a single vector to be dependent?

Comment: I should say $v_3+v_4$ are dependent on $v_1, v_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$. Then the set $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ is linearly dependent since

$$v_1 + v_2 - v_3 = v_1 + v_2 - (v_1 + v_2) = 0.$$

Remark: It does not make sense to say that a vector is linearly dependent without specifying what other vectors it is linearly dependent on. Therefore, we typically talk about linearly dependent sets.

Comment: I believe it is quite clear that this answers the question. The only reasonable interpretation is that the OP is supposed to show that the set $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3 + v_4\}$ is linearly dependent. He is probably new to linear algebra and formulating mathematics in words is difficult. We should show some good-will on this site in stead of actively seeking out posts to downvote. This answers gives a hint as to how to proceed without giving away the entire computation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have rephrased the question.

Comment: I understood what you meant @SquishyPanda. Can you see how to generalize the argument above to the case you want to consider?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. So $(x_1+y_1)v_1+(x_2+y_2)v_2=v_3+v_4$ is sufficient to show that $v_1, v_2, v_3+v_4$ are dependent?

Comment: Because $(x_1+y_1)v_1+(x_2+y_2)v_2-(v_3+v_4)=(x_1+y_1)v_1+(x_2+y_2)v_2-((x_1+y_1)v_1+(x_2+y_2)v_2) =0$ ?

Comment: @SquishyPanda Yes, and clearly not all of the coefficients are zero, so the vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: I see, thanks for all the answers!